# How to improve JQuery performans when toggling lots of columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-plugins

I have the following code, that toggles (show or hides) lots of table cells, the cell to hide is based on the position of the checkbox (one checkbox per TH)

```
    $('.selector input:checkbox').on('change', function () {

        var $checkbox = $(this);
        var index = $('.selector input:checkbox').index($checkbox) + 1;
        var selector = 'tr td:nth-child(' + index + '), tr th:nth-child(' + index + ')';
        $table.find(selector).toggle({
            showOrHide: $checkbox.is(':checked')
        });

    });
```

What I am noticing is there is a noticable delay on click/change of the checkbox. Is there a more efficient way for me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to show or hide columns, you might consider using colgroup elements, then hiding or showing the colgroup by adding or removing a class value. Also, you can modify a CSS rule to show or hide nth child cells rather than using a selector to find them and hide/show them individually (i.e. use CSS not jQuery).

Here is a sample using plain js, it just shows the concept, there are plenty of ways to implement it. I'm sure you can convert it to whatever library suits. The actual code to toggle the class is a single line, the rest is sufficient library code of simple functions to support it.

```
// Function to hide or show a column
function toggleColumn(element, idx) {
  toggleClass(document.getElementById('cg' + idx), 'hidden');
}

// Remove leading and trailing spaces, Replace multiple spaces with single
function trim(s) {
  return s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ');
}

// Return true if element has className, otherwise false
function hasClass(element, className) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') > -1;
}

// Add className to element if it doesn't already have it
function addClass(element, className) {
  if (!hasClass(element, className))
    element.className = trim(element.className + ' ' + className);
}

// Remove className if element has it
function removeClass(element, className)
  if (hasClass(element, className))
    element.className = trim((' ' + element.className + ' ').replace( ' ' + className + ' ',' '));
}

// If element has className, remove it, otherwise, add it
function toggleClass(element, className) {
  hasClass(element, className)? removeClass(element, className) :
                                addClass(element, className);
}
```

Some related CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
</style>
```

And some markup:

```
<table>
  <colgroup id="cg0" span="1"></colgroup>
  <colgroup id="cg1" span="1"></colgroup>
  <colgroup id="cg2" span="1"></colgroup>
  <colgroup id="cg3" span="1"></colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleColumn(this, 1)">
    <th>Column 1
    <th><input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleColumn(this, 3)">
    <th>Column 2
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;<td>1<td>&nbsp;<td>2
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;<td>1<td>&nbsp;<td>2
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;<td>1<td>&nbsp;<td>2
</tables>
```

Comment: Bear in mind the difficulties with using `td:nth-child()` to show/hide columns if any of those `td` elements should have a `colspan` attribute set (to anything other than `1`).